# Viewing the stack when attached to a process - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Excuse the ignorance, I'm new to VS2019.  Back in the dark ages of 2002, I used VS6, and was able to attach to any running process, hit break, and see the call stack and assembly.  I haven't programmed windows stuff since...

I'm trying to do this today with the latest VS2019 and it does not work.  I can tell the application I am attaching to is a .NET application, so I would think there should be plenty of source pdb files also.  But when I hit break, I can see the modules, but the call stack is empty.  And since I can't select a stack frame, I assume, I can't see any source for it either.

I tried right clicking in the call stack window to "show external code" but that does nothing.

[image][image]

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot?

Comment: Attached some pics.

Comment: I see that source code is available for other threads. Try exploring your threads in the "Threads" panel. Double click on a thread to switch to its context. You should see call stacks for some of them. Maybe you will find what you want.

Comment: Hmm.  Clicking on other threads does seem to bring up some of the call stacks.  Why can't I see all of them?

Comment: Not sure, but some threads might be utility threads created by .NET without any associated managed code. The question is, do you see what you want?